# generating histogram chart with 3 columns into 1 column

Tags: python, django-templates, google-visualization

i am genearting the column chart but now i want to generate the histogram for that data which is in this manner

```
['name',10,7,3]
```

now i am getting an problem for genearting the histogram, i wants my chart as only 1 column which shows both pass(7) and fail(3) with different colors out of total(10).

i am doing this in django template. code is

```
 google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart','table']});
  function drawVisualization() {
    // Some raw data (not necessarily accurate)
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
         ['Job-Names', 'Total', 'Pass', 'Fail'],
             {{data.0|safe}}
```

]);

```
    var options = {
      title : 'Jenkins Job Details for project {{head_title}}',
      vAxis: {title: "Number of BULDS" ,ticks : [2,4,6,8,10] },
      hAxis: {title: "Job-Names" ,  slantedText:true, slantedTextAngle:30  , textStyle : {fontSize : 9}},
      is3D: true,
      height: 550,
      width: 600,
      colors : ["#194D86","#33FF66", "#FF3333"],
      pointSize: 4

    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.Histogram(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);

    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
    table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: false});
  }

     google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
```

data i pass in the below format
['name',total,pass,fail]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your needs correctly, I think what you want to do is create a DataView for the HistogramChart that shows only the name, pass, and fail columns:

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([0, 2, 3]);

var chart = new google.visualization.Histogram(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(view, options);
```